# Change AWS SageMaker LogGroup Prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have applications for multiple tenants on our AWS account and would like to distinguish between them in different IAM roles. In most places this is already possible by limiting resource access based on naming patterns.

For CloudWatch log groups of SageMaker training jobs however I have not seen a working solution yet. The tenants can choose the job name arbitrarily, and hence the only part of the LogGroup name that is available for pattern matching would be the prefix before the job name. This prefix however seems to be fixed to `/aws/sagemaker/TrainingJobs`.

Is there a way to change or extend this prefix in order to make such limiting possible? Say, for example `/aws/sagemaker/TrainingJobs/<product>-<stage>-<component>/<training-job-name>-...` so that a resource limitation like `/aws/sagemaker/TrainingJobs/<product>-*` becomes possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to change the log streams names for any of the SageMaker services.

Comment: This has already been confirmed by AWS. The LogGroup names of SageMaker are fixed. It's a pity but can't do much about it.